Next JS 14: В режиме сборки, запросы fetch не идут ибо последние актуальные данные, которые находяться в БД, не видны
В режиме разработки все нормально. Все запросы fetch идут и видны актуальные данные с БД. Но когда собираю приложение (deploy), новые данные, которые записываються в БД, не видны либо не обновляються, либо может даже запросы не идут при входе на сайт, не понятно.
Прошу ознакомиться с кодом, которое получает с /api (он так же правильно настроен по пути /api/news/route.js) новости. И все кстати делал на SSR, чтобы с SEO проблем не было:
import Header from "@/components/Main/Header/Header";
import TournamentBlock from "@/components/Main/TournamentBlock/TournamentBlock";
import config from '../../../public/conf.json';
import VKPosts from "@/components/Main/VKPosts/VKPosts";
import NewsFeed from "@/components/Main/NewsFeed/NewsFeed";
import Broadcasts from "@/components/Main/Broadcasts/Broadcasts";
import TVSchedule from "@/components/Main/TVSchedule/TVSchedule";
import Tags from "@/components/Main/Tags/Tags";
import TransferList from "@/components/Main/TransferList/TransferList";

async function fetchNews() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`http://78.46.254.73:3000/api/news`, { cache: 'no-cache' });
      const data = await res.json();
      
      return data;
    } 
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
}

const Page = async () => {
    const news = await fetchNews();
    const reversedData = await news && news.reverse();

    return (
        <>
        <Header news={reversedData} />
        <TournamentBlock news={reversedData} leagueId={config.mainPageLeagueIds[0]} />
        <div className="newsFeeds">
            <NewsFeed news={reversedData} />
            <VKPosts />
        </div>
        <TournamentBlock news={reversedData} leagueId={config.mainPageLeagueIds[1]} />
        <div className="broadcasts-tv-schedule">
            <Broadcasts />
            <TVSchedule />
        </div>
        <div className="tags-transfers">
            <Tags news={reversedData} />
            <TransferList />
        </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Page;

Так же пробовал сделать getServerSideProps, но внутри компонента когда вызываю "props", она выводит - "undefined". Так же использовал { cache: 'no-cache' } чтобы данные закешировались в том случае, если они новые.
Прошу помочь с данной проблемой. В случае неправильного написания кода и самой проблемы - критика приветствуется.
